# Python application logging with Azure Log Analytics

Tags: python, azure, logging, flask, azure-log-analytics

I have a small Python (Flask) application running in a Docker container.
The container orchestrator is Kubernetes, all running in Azure.

What is the best approach to set up centralized logging? (similar to Graylog)
Is it possible to get the application logs over OMS to Azure Log Analytics?

Thank you,
Tibor

Comment: Tibor can you have a look at my answer below. If you managed to solve your problem another way, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement. I have a continuously running Python application running in a Docker container. So far I have found that the Azure SDK for Python supports lots of integration into Azure from Python. This page might be able to help:

https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-logging/

Here is also a package and guide how to set up Blob Storage and enable logging:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/azure-storage-blob